# how do i make the password and username tabs centerd to eachother

Tags: html, css

I was wandering if there is a way to center the password and username tab under eachother? Also if you see a way to make this code shorter pleas tell me. I am a noob at html so there is probably some wrongs in this code. Ty before hand, Lukas Mocko!

```css
p.mom {
  padding-top: 16em
}

p.dad {
  padding-top: 1em
}

p.car {
  padding-left: 56.5em
}

p.car {
  padding-top: 1em
}
```

```html
<center>

  <head>
    <style>

    </style>



    <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">



      <p class="mom">
        <label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</
  </p class="mom">
   <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text 
    name="user_name" required />



  <p class="dad">
  <label 
 for="login_input_password">&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;пароль</label>
        <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />
      </p class="dad">

</center>

<p class="car">
  <input type="submit" name="login" value="авторизоваться" />
</p class="car">

</form>
</head>
```

Comment: you need to start by correcting you HTML, you have bad syntax and obsolete tags

Answer (score 2):

you can use `display: flex;` property of css to do this

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
<div>
    <label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</label>
    <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_name" required />
</div>
<div>
    <label for="login_input_password">пароль</label>
    <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="авторизоваться" />
</div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form{
   flex: 1;
   display: flex;
   height: 250px;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
}
form div{
   margin-bottom: 10px;
}
form div label{
   display: flex;
}
form div button{
   display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
    <div>
        <label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</label>
        <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_name" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="login_input_password">пароль</label>
        <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="авторизоваться" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
form{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    height: 250px;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

form div{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

form div label{
    display: flex;
}

form div button{
    display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
<div style="align-items:center; display: flex; flex-direction: column;">
<div>
<label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</label><br/>
<input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" 
name="user_name">
</div>
<div>
<label 
for="login_input_password">пароль</label><br/>
<input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" 
name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />
</div>
<div>
<br />
<input type="submit"  name="login" value="авторизоваться" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
p.dad, .car {
  padding-top: 1em;
}

/* center div */

.form-center{ 
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="form-center">
 <form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">

    <p class="mom">
    <label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</label>
    </p>
    <input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_name" required />

    <p class="dad">
     <label for="login_input_password">пароль</label>
    </p>
     <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required />

    </center>

    <p class="car">
      <input type="submit" name="login" value="авторизоваться" />
    </p>

  </form>
</div>
```

EDITED: I change code.

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
   form {
      text-align:center;
    }
   table{margin:  auto;}
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="loginform">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td><label for="login_input_username">имя пользователя</label></td>
                <td><input id="login_input_username" class="login_input" type="text" name="user_name" required=""></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td> <label for="login_input_password">пароль</label></td>
                <td> <input id="login_input_password" class="login_input" type="password" name="user_password" autocomplete="off" required=""></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>

    </form>
```